# How to reuse Raw Input Buffer memory?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

After spending a whole day, I a finally figured out how to use the Win32 `GetRawInputBuffer` to read input from my mouse.

However I don't like the fact that I have create a new `std::vector` each frame, so I tried making `std::vector<RAWINPUT> raw_inputs` a class member and call `GetRawInputBuffer` with the same `raw_inputs` expecting `GetRawInputBuffer` to overwrite the the content but instead the frequency of reported input drop significantly.

If I zero the memory after the first call with `{0}` the program crashes.

```
std::vector<RAWINPUT> raw_inputs;  // if I make this a class member it stops after the first call
raw_inputs.resize(1024);
uint32_t raw_input_size = (uint32_t)(sizeof(RAWINPUT) * raw_inputs.size());

UINT input_count = GetRawInputBuffer(raw_inputs.data(), &raw_input_size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));       

if (input_count == (UINT)-1) {
    return ErrorStack(ExtraError::FAILED_TO_GET_RAW_INPUT_BUFFER, code_location, "failed to get raw input buffer", getLastError());
}
else if (input_count) {
    printf("input_count = %d \n", input_count);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < input_count; i++) {

        RAWINPUT& raw_input = raw_inputs[i];

        if (raw_input.header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE) {
            printf("%d %d \n", raw_input.data.mouse.lLastX, raw_input.data.mouse.lLastY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this code run? Do you poll the input in some window message handler? Please post some more code.

Comment: Refer to official sample "[Performing a Buffered Read of Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/using-raw-input#performing-a-buffered-read-of-raw-input)". Showing a mini, complete and reproducible sample is helpful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score -1):

Finally figured out you have to call the `clear` method on `std::vector` before passing the vector again to `GetRawInputBuffer`.

```
void calledSomeWhere() 
{
    static std::vector<RAWINPUT> raw_inputs;

    raw_inputs.clear();
    raw_inputs.resize(1024);
    uint32_t raw_input_size = (uint32_t)(sizeof(RAWINPUT) * raw_inputs.size());

    UINT input_count = GetRawInputBuffer(raw_inputs.data(), &raw_input_size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));       

    if (input_count == (UINT)-1) {
        return ErrorStack(ExtraError::FAILED_TO_GET_RAW_INPUT_BUFFER, code_location, "failed to get raw input buffer", getLastError());
    }
    else if (input_count) {
        printf("input_count = %d \n", input_count);

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < input_count; i++) {

            RAWINPUT& raw_input = raw_inputs[i];

            if (raw_input.header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE) {
                printf("%d %d \n", raw_input.data.mouse.lLastX, raw_input.data.mouse.lLastY);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You DON'T have to call `clear()`+`resize()` on the `std::vector` to reuse it. `clear()` will just set the `vector`'s `size()` to 0 and destroy the current elements (a no-op for a POD type like `RAWINPUT`) but preserves the `capacity()`. `resize()` sets the `size()`, and only if the new `size()` exceeds the `capacity()` then the `capacity()` is increased. All new elements are default-initialized, which for a POD type is no different than using `ZeroMemory()`. Calling `clear()`+`resize(1024)` on a vector whose `capacity()` is >= 1024 effectively preserves the physical array and just zeros it out

Comment: I know that I tried before but it only works like this, that's why I asked the question

Comment: Then you likely did something else wrong with it. You said reusing the same `vector` buffer doesn't work, but using `clear()`+`resize(1024)` the way you have shown is doing exactly that! So please edit your question to show what you have actually tried that isn't working for you.